# does calling $el.remove() remove eventhandlers on nested dom-elements as well?

Tags: jquery

Just a a double-check: does calling `$el.remove()` remove eventhandlers on nested dom-elements as well (in addition to deleting eventhandlers bound to the element itself)?

Comment: just check the documentation http://api.jquery.com/remove/ `Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.`

Comment: ahh yes, missed that when quickly scanning said page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

> Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.

So I would say yes.

Here's a simple test:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="target">Click me!</div>
    </div>
</div>

$("#target").click(function() {
    alert("clicked");
});

var target = $("#target");
$("#inner").remove();
$("#outer").append(target);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4BCP/

So I attach a handler to a nested div, then I delete it's parent and append it back to it's grandparent. The click handler is no longer bound.

Compare with: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4BCP/1/

Which uses `.detach()` instead of `.remove()`